# TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str(): Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

From a search it seems like one can get this error in a whole host of different situations. Here is mine:

```
testDf['pA'] = priorDf.loc[testDf['Period']]['a'] + testDf['TotalPlays']

--> 743     sorter = uniques.argsort()
    744 
    745     reverse_indexer = np.empty(len(sorter), dtype=np.int64)

TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

where `priorDf.loc[testDf['Period']]['a']`is:

```
Period
2-17-1    1.120947
1-14-1    1.181726
7-19-1    1.935126
4-08-1    3.828184
3-14-1    0.668255
```

and `testDf['TotalPlays']` is:

```
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
```

Both are of length 48.

----Additional Info-----

```
print (priorDf.dtypes)
mean    float64
var     float64
a       float64
b       float64
dtype: object

print (testDf.dtypes)
UserID          int64
Period         object
PlayCount       int64
TotalPlays      int64
TotalWks        int64
Prob          float64
pA              int64
dtype: object
```

----- More Info ---------

```
print (priorDf['a'].head()) 

Period
1-00-1    0.889164
1-01-1    2.304074
1-02-1    0.281502
1-03-1    1.137781
1-04-1    2.335650
Name: a, dtype: float64

print (testDf[['Period','TotalPlays']].head()) 

   Period  TotalPlays
0  2-17-1           1
1  1-14-1           1
2  7-19-1           1
3  4-08-1           1
4  3-14-1           1
```

I also tried converting `priorDf.loc[testDf['Period']]['a']` to type int (as it was a float) but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `priorDf['a']` or `dict` created from it.

Problem was different `indexes` of `DataFrames`, so data cannot align.

```
#changed data of Period for match sample data
print (testDf)
   Period  TotalPlays
0  1-00-1           1
1  1-14-1           1
2  7-19-1           1
3  4-08-1           1
4  1-04-1           1

testDf['pA'] = testDf['Period'].map(priorDf['a']) + testDf['TotalPlays']
print (testDf)
   Period  TotalPlays        pA
0  1-00-1           1  1.889164
1  1-14-1           1       NaN
2  7-19-1           1       NaN
3  4-08-1           1       NaN
4  1-04-1           1  3.335650
```

---

```
print (priorDf['a'].to_dict())
{'1-02-1': 0.28150199999999997, '1-01-1': 2.304074, 
'1-00-1': 0.88916399999999995, '1-03-1': 1.1377809999999999, 
'1-04-1': 2.3356499999999998}

testDf['pA'] = testDf['Period'].map(priorDf['a'].to_dict()) + testDf['TotalPlays']
print (testDf)
   Period  TotalPlays        pA
0  1-00-1           1  1.889164
1  1-14-1           1       NaN
2  7-19-1           1       NaN
3  4-08-1           1       NaN
4  1-04-1           1  3.335650
```

Comment: Have added dtype info above. Let me sort out the indexes and see what happens.

Comment: Ok I've re-written the code to this: 

testDf.set_index('Period',inplace=True)

testDf['pA'] = priorDf.loc[testDf.index]['a'] + testDf['TotalPlays'] and it appears to work (will have to do a closer inspection).  

But feel like my original ought to have worked too as the two series were in the right order.

Comment: Yes, it seems it shoul works. `testDf['Period'].map(priorDf['a'])` get same output as `priorDf.loc[testDf.index]['a']` ?

Comment: Yep - those two gave the exact same results.

Comment: If still some problem, is possible add samples `print (priorDf['a'].head())
print (testDf[['Period','TotalPlays']].head())` to question?

Comment: Done. Even though I can move on using the method above it would be good to get to the bottom of this as it's really puzzling. Both of these also work fine: `testDf['TotalPlays'] + 1` and   `Z.astype(int)+1`   where (Z =priorDf.loc[testDf['Period']]['a'])

Answer (score 0):

So my conclusion after testing with randomly generated values `S = pd.Series(np.random.randn(48))` is that when adding columns from two different series together, they have to have the same Index. Pandas must automatically be sorting them both behind the scenes or something. So in my case I had period as the index for one, and period as a column, not the index for the other.

My re-written solution was:

```
testDf.set_index('Period', inplace=True)
testDf['pA'] = priorDf.loc[testDf.index]['a'] + testDf['TotalPlays']
testDf['pB'] = priorDf.loc[testDf.index]['b'] + testDf['TotalWks']-testDf['TotalPlays']
```

Thanks to jezrael  for helping me get to the bottom of it.